# Loading external data into phonegap using Jquery Json P

Tags: jquery, cordova, jsonp

I have following json object that i get from my local mysql.

```
<([{"ID":"1","Title":"Chicken & Chili","Price":"$8.99","ImageURL":"\/images\/dinner\/chicchili.jpg","Serves":"2","Description":"This unique and delicious chicken chili is a much-requested meal around our house. I think you'll find it's a nice change of pace from the typical beef version."},{"ID":"2","Title":"Chicken Franchase","Price":"$9.99","ImageURL":"\/images\/dinner\/chicfran.jpg","Serves":"2","Description":"Served in a lemon and butter sauce"},{"ID":"3","Title":"Salmon","Price":"$14.99","ImageURL":"\/images\/dinner\/salmon.jpg","Serves":"1","Description":"A simple soy sauce and brown sugar marinade, with hints of lemon and garlic, are the perfect salty-sweet complement to rich salmon fillets."}]);
```

i used following code to get the json object into the iPhone simulator. I am successful getting title and price on the screen but not images.Is there any way to get the images ? Or am i missing something in coding.Any suggestion please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var output = $('#output');
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost/Backend/getDinner.php',
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data, status){
  $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
    var Menu_Dinner = '<li><a href="detail.html?id=' + item.ID + '">' +
      '<img src="images/dinner/'+ item.ImageURL + '">' +
    '<h2 class="ui-li-heading">' + item.Title + '</h2 >' + 
    '<h2>' + 'Price: ' + item.Price + '</h2>'+ '</a></li>';
    output.append(Menu_Dinner);
  });
},
error: function(){
  output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
}
```

});
});

Comment: Try removing the leading forward slash on the image path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you need to change the link path. Example:

1. if inside your database the image URL path is: `images/dinner/picture.jpg` then the code needs to be: `'<img src="' + item.ImageURL + '">'`
2. if your image URL path is just `picture.jpg` then you can use your existing code.

I don't know if the simulator has a console window you can view, if it does add the following line to the end of the `success` function and inspect each list item for its href property:

```
console.log($("#output").html());
```

As a side, try to minimise the number of times that you manipulate the DOM. So try this inside:

```
var temp = "";
$.each(data, function(i,item){ 
  var Menu_Dinner = '<li><a href="detail.html?id=' + item.ID + '">' +
    '<img src="images/dinner/'+ item.ImageURL + '">' +
    '<h2 class="ui-li-heading">' + item.Title + '</h2 >' + 
    '<h2>' + 'Price: ' + item.Price + '</h2>'+ '</a></li>';
  temp += Menu_Dinner;
});
output.append(temp);
```